# ggplot2 - manually fix number of groups required by the "fill" variable in the aes mapping in an incomplete data set

Tags: r, ggplot2, mapping, facet-wrap

I want to generate facetted boxplots and overlay them with geom_point for multiple lab parameters. The plots should be split along age_group, in the age groups the status of patients should be compared next to each other.
Here's what my mapping looks like:
aes(x=Age_group2, y=value, fill=Status)

This is the overall code for generating my report:

```
pdf("lab10.pdf")
for (i in 1:number_of_facets_lab){
  print(ggplot(lab_merge_clean, aes(x=Age_group2, y=value, fill=Status)) +
          geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA, position = position_dodge2(width = 0.7,preserve="total"), 
          width = 0.6) +
          geom_point(data = lab_merge_clean %>% filter(max_WHO_classification >= 3 & 
          analysis.identifier != "COV006"),
                     position = position_dodge(width = 0.6, preserve="total"),
                     shape = 16,alpha = 0.7, size = 2.5)+
          geom_point(data = lab_merge_clean %>% filter(max_WHO_classification < 3),
                     position = position_dodge(width = 0.6, preserve="total"),
                     shape = 1, alpha = 0.7, size = 2.5) +
          geom_point(data = lab_merge_clean %>% filter(analysis.identifier=="COV006" ),
                     position = position_dodge(width = 0.6, preserve = "total"),
                     shape = 1, alpha = 0.7, size = 2.5, colour = "red", fill = "red") +
          scale_fill_manual(values = c("lightskyblue2", "orange2"))+
          facet_wrap_paginate(~ lab_parameter, scales = "free_y", ncol = 1, nrow = 1, page = i) +
          theme_bw() +
          stat_compare_means(aes(label = paste0("p =", ..p.format..))) +
          scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0.05, 0.2))) +theme_classic() + 
          theme( axis.text = element_text( size = 14 ),
                 axis.text.x = element_text( size = 20 ),
                 axis.title = element_text( size = 16, face = "bold" ),
                 legend.position="none",
                 strip.text = element_text(size = 20))
        )
  print(i)
}
dev.off()
```

In the best case the result looks like this:

[image]

But sometimes this happens:

[image]

The boxplot is shifted, because there are no observations in the other group. This is why I want to manually fix the number of groups in the fill variable, so that the plots will not get shifted and align with the geom_point dots.

I have looked up solutions on stack, but I haven't managed to find an answer yet. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for `position_dodge2` with `preserve = "single"` but a `preserve = "total"` on the `geom_point`?

```r
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(1)

df <- data.frame(y = rnorm(30), 
                 x = c(rep("A", 20), rep("B", 10)), 
                 z = rep(c("1", "2", "1"), each = 10))

ggplot(df, aes(x, y, fill = z)) +
  geom_boxplot(position = position_dodge2(width = 1, preserve = "single"), 
               width = 0.8) +
  geom_point(position = position_dodge(width = 0.8, preserve = "total")) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("lightskyblue2", "orange2")) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]